# C# Odbc Stored procedure call - Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, odbc

I have a basic stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrdersEmailContent] 
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Body nvarchar(2000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @Body = (SELECT Content 
                 FROM ORDERS_tblEmailContent
                 WHERE Name = @Name)
END
```

which I am calling from C# with the following code

```
using (DbConnection)
{
    DbConnection.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        DbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DbCommand.CommandText = " GetOrdersEmailContent";

        DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
        DbCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = templateName;
        DbCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Body", OdbcType.NVarChar, 2000);
        DbCommand.Parameters["@Body"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        DbCommand.Parameters["@Body"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        emailBody = DbCommand.Parameters["@Body"].Value.ToString();   
    }
}

DbConnection.Close();
```

When the `ExecuteNonQuery` runs, it returns the following error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'GetOrdersEmailContent' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.

Can anyone advise? I have looked through other similar questions but none of the solutions apply or resolve the issue

Comment: can you try this `DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = templateName;`

Comment: are you sure `templateName` is not null?

Comment: Kashi_rock - I'm afraid this has not made any difference

Comment: In general, you need to check for "nullable" arguments.  Regardless if this fixes the issue or not, you should change the "set value" code for @Name to ..................................  DbCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : templateName;

Comment: And there's small chance it fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

Considering `templateName` have not empty. There is not need to specify direction for `@Name`:

```
using (DbConnection)
        {
            DbConnection.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                DbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DbCommand.CommandText = " GetOrdersEmailContent";

                DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
                DbCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = templateName;

                DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Body", OdbcType.NVarChar, 2000);
                DbCommand.Parameters["@Body"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                DbCommand.Parameters["@Body"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                emailBody = DbCommand.Parameters["@Body"].Value.ToString();   
            }
        }
        DbConnection.Close();
```